# creating an object variable in rspec test but got nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

here is my rspec code:

```
describe User do
  before{(@user=User.new(username:"abcdefg",email:"123456@123.com",password:"123456")}
  subject(@user)
  @user.save
end
```

and I got such an error : `undefined method 'save' for nil:NilClass(NoMethodError)`

I try to write the same code in the rails console,it just worked. But when it comes to Rspec,it failed and I'm not able to find any reason...

Could any one help me with it?

Comment: It may have worked for you in the console if you had already defined `@user` previously in the same session

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the code in an example block (i.e., call the `it` method with a block), because in the context of the `describe` block, `@user` is not defined. For example:

```
describe User do
  before{(@user=User.new(username:"abcdefg",email:"123456@123.com",password:"123456")}
  subject(@user)

  it "can be saved" do
    @user.should respond_to(:save)
    @user.save.should_not be_false
  end
end
```

**Edit:** I noticed also that you have `subject(@user)` but that may need to be a block in order to set it properly. The following is cleaner overall:

```
describe User do
  let(:user) { User.new(username:"abcdefg",email:"123456@123.com",password:"123456") }

  it "can be saved" do
    user.should respond_to(:save)
    user.save.should_not be_false
  end
end
```

Comment: `@user.save.should_not be_false` to make it a true test ;)

Answer (score 7):

here is the Rspec way:

```
describe User do
  let(:valid_user) { User.new(username:"abcdefg",email:"123456@123.com",password:"123456") }

  it "can be saved" do
    expect(valid_user.save).to be_true
  end
end
```

Note that you should avoid database operations in your specs, it's what make them slow.

Another point, consider using factories to clean up your specs.

Comment: +1 as this is indeed a right answer like it is supposed to be done.